# How to use DDD aggregates with TimeSeries?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to implement a more DDD oriented solution for managing time series data. Following code examples and patterns to be found here [eShopOnWeb](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb). In essence there are three entities. `Site`, `Signal` and `Sample`. A `Site` can have a collection of `Signals` and a `Signal` can have a collection of samples.

```
    public class Site: BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        // Collection loaded by EFCore through Repository
        private List<Signal> signals = new List<Signal>();

        // Public read only access
        public IEnumerable<Signal> Signals => this.signals.AsReadOnly();
    }
```

```
    public class Signal: BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        // Signal has to belong to Site
        public int SiteId { get; private set; }

        // Typical EF Nav property removed
        // Signal should have no access to it's 'parent' properties
        // public Site Site { get; set;}

        private List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();

        public IEnumerable<Sample> Samples => this.samples.AsReadOnly();
    }
```

```
    public class Sample : BaseEntity
    {
        public int SignalId { get; private set; }

        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        public double? Value { get; set; }
    }
```

As a first pass, and having struggled without the Evans or Vernon books available (they are in the post), I've settled on there being two AggregateRoots with `Site` the more prominant one. That is a `Signal` aggregate should really be accessed through the `Site`.

The major issue I've found is with loading subsets of `Samples` to the `Signal`.

As per the `Specification` pattern used in the [eShopOnWeb](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) examples I can fairly easily work with the `Site` aggregate and load it's `Signals` aggregate collection with a call against a `SiteRepository` in the `Infrastructure` layer:

```
    public sealed class SiteFilterSpecification : BaseSpecification<Site>
    {
        public SiteFilterSpecification(int id)
            : base(s => s.Id == id)
        {
            this.AddInclude(s => s.Signals);
        }
    }
```

If I'm in a `Service` class where I've been supplied a Site and period of time over which something is to be calculated, usually involving multiple `Signals` the Specification pattern would suggest something like:

```
    public double GetComplexProcess(Site site, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var specification = new SiteSignalsWithSamplesSpec(site.Id, start, end);
        var signals = this.SignalRepository.List(specification);

        // signals should be loaded with the appropriate samples...
    }
```

The problem I've found here is that in the Specification it's not possible to filter the `Samples` which are included with the `Signal`

```
    public sealed class SiteSignalsWithSamplesSpecification : BaseSpecification<Signal>
    {
        public SiteSignalsWithSamplesSpecification(int siteId, DateTime from, DateTime end)
            : base(s => s.SiteId == siteId)
        {
            // This throws exception at runtime
            this.AddInclude(s => s.Samples.Where(sa => sa.TimeStamp >= from && sa.TimeStamp <= end));
        }
    }
```

You can use this approach and load all of the `Samples` but when handling time series data this can mean hundreds of thousands of entities when what we really need is a focused selection of them.

What I'm currently doing; and this doesn't feel particularly "clean" is to implement a version of the Generic Repository class specifically for the partial loading of `Sample` data on `Signal` entities.

```
    public interface ISignalRepository : IAsyncRepository<Signal>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Signal>> GetBySiteIdWithSamplesAsync(int siteId, DateTime from, DateTime to);
    }
```

```
    public class SignalRepository : EfRepository<Signal>, ISignalRepository
    {
        public SignalRepository(ForecastingContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Signal>> GetBySiteIdWithSamplesAsync(int siteId, DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            var signals = await this.dbContext.Signals.Where(s => s.SiteId == siteId).ToListAsync();

            foreach (var signal in signals)
            {
                this.dbContext.Entry(signal)
                    .Collection(s => s.Samples)
                    .Query()
                    .Where(s => s.TimeStamp >= from && s.TimeStamp <= to)
                    .Load();
            }

            return signals;
        }
    }
```

It's probably just the initial uncertainty that comes with developing in a new pattern, but this somehow feels wrong.

Is it correct that I'm using two Aggregates?

Answer (score 1):

> The more difficult issue is how to load the Sample entities

I have found that I need to be careful distinguishing two different kinds of information; information where my model is the authority, and reference data.

You might want to review [Data on the Outside vs Data on the Inside](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf).

Signals from sensors out in the real world don't belong to our model.  We're just storing copies of it *here* because that's more cost effective than trying to store it all *there*.  Thus, we don't need "aggregates" when the task at hand is reference data capture.

That said, we're capturing the data because we want to do *something* with it, sure -- so we may have a domain model that aggregates partitions of our captured data together to perform interesting calculations.  But that -- in the experiences I have had -- is a *concurrent* behavior; the process of aggregating the data shouldn't block us from collecting more.

Instead, what it often looks like is a stream of data coming in from the outside world, and in internal process that does bookkeeping, with an updated reference that tracks where it is in the history of signals that have arrived.

Comment: That’s going to need a serious cup of coffee; I’ll read it over tomorrow and see where we go.

Comment: Good paper; it’s interesting seeing how the concepts have evolved over the years and how microservices and Domain Events build on it. So... the comment. Yes I agree, it’s what we’re doing. Lots of external services feeding data to this application(pulling rather pushing, but that’s a later refactoring) the code managing this operates at the SampleRepository level; which is acceptable since its EFCore and carrying out bulk operations for performance. I would love to have the ApplicationServices working more DDD though, which implies Site.Signal.Samples semantics. I’ve updated my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also worth remembering, that DDD is much more than the tactical patterns. The aggregate model makes sense when we have complex write models, where you want to protect the transaction boundary.
Timeseries though, as it has been mentioned already, are a collection of events, where besides doing type-safety control (booleans vs numbers), you don't have business invariants protecting the state of the entity. In fact, we could go to say that you just have a collection of values, but no entity exists, unless you want to use the timestamp as the identifier of a given schema. But that's mostly mental gymnastic, not something that the SMEs in the problem space would really consider to be an identifier of an entity. There is no further mutation to that entity, is just a read operation on time that happened once.

Timeseries are append-only models. There is no much value on trying to force the aggregate and repository patterns to a model that's not intrinsically related to what Evans and Vernon had in mind when they wrote their books.

What does remain in place though are the strategical aspects, bounded context, ubiquitous language and integration patterns.

I would recommend instead to pay attention to those concerns more than trying to force the code to adhere to a model that is not well suited for, creating an artificial impedance mismatch.